# How Cisco Line Protocol works

Tags: cisco, switch, router, ethernet

How do Cisco Line Protocol works ?

I could read this: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/content-networking/keepalives/118390-technote-keepalive-00.html, about Ethernet Interfaces keepalive mechanisms .

Is this mechanism up to date ? Especially regarding modern technologies like GigabitEthernet and TenGigabitEthernet .

Are those the same techniques for optical fibers?

Comment: Do you have a practical problem with a serial line? The keepalive mechanism is something you add on top of various protocols.

Comment: Typically for the data link layer connection detection for Cisco devices. The second UP status of the interface.